# How to Set ImageView in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, imageview

I understand that we cannot set ImageView in AsyncTask. But I need to add the ImageView into HashMap and the HashMap need to add into an ArrayList inside the for loop. I cannot do that in onPostExecute(). Does anyone know how to do?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.1.132/retEqp.php";
    ImageView iv; 


    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "equipments";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "item_ID";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "item_Name";
    private static final String TAG_DESC = "item_Desc";
    private static final String TAG_LOC = "item_Location";
    private static final String TAG_STATUS = "item_Status";
    private static final String TAG_IMAGE = "item_Image";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray equipments = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

        iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img2);


        // Hashmap for ListView
        productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllProducts().execute();



        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                        .toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent previousScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewProductActivity.class);
                 //Sending the data to NewProductActivity
                 previousScreen.putExtra("id",pid); 
                 setResult(1000, previousScreen);

                finish();   

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back

            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();



        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
           // Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {

                    equipments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < equipments.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = equipments.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = "ID: "+c.getString(TAG_PID);
                        String name = "Name: "+c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        String desc = "Description: "+c.getString(TAG_DESC);
                        String loc = "Location: "+c.getString(TAG_LOC);
                        String status = "Status: "+c.getString(TAG_STATUS);
                        String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);



                        byte[] rawImage = Base64.decode(image, Base64.DEFAULT);
                        Bitmap bmp12 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawImage, 0, rawImage.length);
                        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp12);


                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                       // map.put(TAG_IMAGE, rawImage.length);

                        map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                        map.put(TAG_DESC, desc);
                        map.put(TAG_LOC, loc);
                        map.put(TAG_STATUS, status);
                        map.put(TAG_IMAGE, iv.toString());



                        // adding HashList to ArrayList

                        productsList.add(map);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_IMAGE,TAG_PID,
                                    TAG_NAME,TAG_DESC,TAG_LOC,TAG_STATUS},
                            new int[] {R.id.img,R.id.pid, R.id.name,R.id.desc,R.id.loc,R.id.status});
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi mike....Why do you add image in doInBackground() of asyncTask..i suggest you to take field in ProductList(ArrayList). And take custome Adapter and set the image in getView() of that custom adapter.

Comment: I would like to add in image in the ArrayList. Inside the ArrayList, every single item will associated with 1 image. Do you know how to set it? @gvsharma

Comment: yes. i'm telling you to take custom adapter instead of SimpleAdapter().
pass the productList as parameter to it and set the views in getView() of that adapter class.

Comment: I duno how to do that, Im still quite new in programming.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the UI in a background thread.

The idea behind AsyncTask is that `doInBackground` does the background work, then you can return something that will be passed as a parameter to `onPostExecute` which is executed in the main thread.

In this case you have to return the parsed model objects from `doInBackground` (I would create a custom class), receive in `onPostExecute`. Also, create a custom adapter, which will take care of creating views. You should generate bitmaps there (probably you have to put the parsing to bitmap in another async task).

Comment: Ya I know that, but the ImageView I have to put into the HashMap <map> and the HashMap has to be put into ArrayList(ProductList). But the action is done by the for loop inside AsyncTask. Is there any way I can put the ImageView into the HashMap also?

Comment: I would suggest that you store your products in a custom model object instead of a map. This way you can set the bitmap as a field of this object in type safe way. Then return the products list in doInBackground and receive is as parameter in onPostExecute. There retrieve the bitmap, set it in the image view.

Comment: May I know how to do that?

Comment: Well: create a class, name it "Product" or similar, add fields with the same name as the keys in your map... add also a field of type Bitmap to store the bitmap. Create instances of this class instead of maps. Return List of Product from doInBackground. Change signature of onPostExecute to accept List of Product instead of string. Iterate through products and set images in image views. Modify type parameters of AsyncTask accordingly.

Comment: Anyway your code looks a bit weird. Also, you have one single image view and a list of products and overwrite the bitmap on each iteration, not clear what you intend to do there.

Comment: The image and products info I retrieve from my remote database. Inside the list, there will be a number of products with the info and also 1 image per product.

Comment: Yeah, and in your activity there is only one image view. An image view can only display one image.

Comment: There is inside a for loop, while every single loop, I create an ImageView, and set the image, put into the HashMap then run the loop again. Is that okay?

Comment: You have to let the adapter create views. Create a custom adapter. Actually, you should generate bitmap also in adapter. Otherwise can run out of memory. So pass map (or custom object) to custom adapter, and create bitmaps there. If you need async task to generate bitmap you will have to create one in the custom adapter.

Comment: Means that, I should create a for loop in the customer adapter in order to retrieve all the images?

Comment: You have to understand adapters. Read for example this article: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html